# How to insert value in sorted array of objects and its sorted on the basis on number in object

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

Array can have duplicate objects having same number.
Example:
[

```
 {NumericOrder : 1, Name:"Test1"},
 {NumericOrder: 1, Name:"Test2"} ,
{NumericOrder:2,Name: "Test 3"},
 {NumericOrder : 3, Name:"Test4"},
 {NumericOrder: 4, Name:"Test5"} ,
{NumericOrder:5,Name: "Test 6"},
```

]

Now I need to insert {NumericOrder: 1 , Name : "Test7"} after  {NumericOrder: 1, Name:"Test2"} ,

I can use binary search and get last index of targeted value. Can I get more efficient solution ?

Comment: binary search is the best you can do to find the right index for the new element, but I'm concerned about you really inserting that element into the array. Array insertion (except for pushing on the top) is O(n) complexity. Ideally, if you want to have a data structure with balanced insertion/deletion/access times, you should go for a treemap/sorted container data structure where all of these operations are logarithmic.

Comment: Binary search itself is highly efficient, with `log(n)` complexity (eg average 30 lookups for 1 billion items). I'm not sure what more you could want given your existing data structure. As mentioned, there are better data structures for this

Comment: I agree with you people but I already have a complex algorithm and this array is used in multiple sections of code. So for the time as suggested I would go for binary search log (n) for getting index and O(N) for insertion.

Comment: If you have to do insertion with O(n) then no need to do a binary search. As your array is sorted in each step, do the insertion at the beginning of the array and swap items until it goes in its place. HOWEVER, if you can add an item by index in O(1) then doing binary search is more efficient.

Comment: If you can wait until all items have been inserted and sort afterwards, that would be even more efficient.

Comment: So, I am adding items first an then sorting data.  What do you think the best way to sort it.  Any specific algo ?